# Can I add A Firebase collection in a collection

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I have a form that collects user information and favourite foods But when collecting favourite food I want the favourite Food collection to be a Child to the 'users' collection Likes:

```
const sendPosts = (e) => {

    e.preventDefault()
    db.collection("users").add({
    
    //here I add the user details
    name: "userName",
    lastName: "userLastName",
    
    //is it possible to also add a collection like this after "lastName"
    
    collection("favFood").add({
    favDrink: "userDrink",
    favDessert: "userDesert",
      })
    })
  }
```

is it possible to do it like that or is it impossible or there is a simple way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible, since the [`add()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference#add) method returns the `DocumentReference` of the newly created document.

```
db.collection("users").add({
    name: "userName",
    lastName: "userLastName"
})
.then(userDocRef => {
    userDocRef.collection("favFood").add({
        favDrink: "userDrink",
        favDessert: "userDesert",
    });
});
```

`userDocRef.collection("favFood")` declares the  `CollectionReference` of the `favFood` subcollection of the newly created `user` document. See the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference#collection).

Comment: Ohh Yes it worked, Thank You